# How to unpickle pickle extension file

Tags: python, linux, file, ubuntu

I have downloaded a pickle file:

```
foo.pickle.gz.pickle
```

The page from where I downloaded this file describes decompressing it to `.pickle`. I searched about python pickle, there are many pages that describe how to use in python, but not system wide. How can I decompress or unzip it? I am using ubuntu 16.04

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

`Pickle` is the name of Python object serialisation module. So, you have to 'unpickle' it with a python script. Basic synthax is:

```
import pickle

with open('filename', 'rb') as pickled_one:
    data = pickle.load(pickled_one)
```

More details are available [here, on official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

I do have to warn you about this, from that same page:

> **The pickle module is not secure against erroneous or maliciously
>   constructed data. Never unpickle data received from an untrusted or
>   unauthenticated source.**

Comment: Does this code snippet generate decompressed file ??

Comment: No, it decompresses contents into a variable. You have to write that variable to a file, possibly after parsing data from the pickle, depending on what you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

Pickle object can only be deserialized in python. You can't use non-python environments to deserialize the object. Please see the official [page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

Comment: Can I save unpicked data to file in python?

Comment: yeah, you can read it in python and save it in whichever format you want, e.g. text, csv, fix width etc. you can use an external standard like json which is readable by other programs. Depends on what kind of object is there in the pickle file.

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple pickled objects, as the answers above only unpickle 1 object.
Use

```py
pickle_list =[]
pickle_file = open(file_name, 'rb')
while True:
    try:
        pickle_list.append(pickle.load(pickle_file))
    except EOFError:
        break
pickle_file.close()
```

Not able to indent the code properly, but try and except are inside the while loop