# Attempt to unpickle a compressed pickle file results in OSError: Invalid data stream

Tags: python, compression, pickle

I have a `compressed pickle` pickle file. On several attempts, I have tried to unpickle this file with no success. Here is the code to unpickle the compressed pickle file based on the following resources [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/load-fast-load-big-with-compressed-pickles-5f311584507e), [here](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pickle-python-tutorial#compressing) and [here](https://gist.github.com/cwidmer/7813392).

First, I try using the `pickle` module.

```
import bz2
import pickle

data = bz2.BZ2File('test.gzip', 'rb')
data = pickle.load(data)
```

Then, I also try with the `cPickle` module.

```
import bz2
import _pickle as cPickle

data = bz2.BZ2File('test.gzip', 'rb')
data = cPickle.load(data)
```

On both attempts, I get an `OSError: Invalid data stream` on the `load()` function. Here's a trace.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Users\jane\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\bz2.py", line 172, in peek
    return self._buffer.peek(n)
  File "C:\Users\jane\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\_compression.py", line 68, in readinto
    data = self.read(len(byte_view))
  File "C:\Users\jane\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\_compression.py", line 103, in read
    data = self._decompressor.decompress(rawblock, size)
OSError: Invalid data stream
```

I thought it may have something to do with my Python environment, but I've tested these snippets of code after create Python environments for Python 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8 in Conda. I still get the same error. I also moved into Ubuntu (WSL) and tried it on a Python 3.8 conda environment, and got the same error.

Any ideas on what's going on?

I looked at these SO posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55681295/how-to-unpickle-pickle-extension-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48712164/oserror-invalid-data-stream-to-load-bz2-pickle-pbz2-serialized-pd-datafram), but the problems and solutions do not really apply.

Comment: Is that the actual file name? ".gzip" (which would normally be ".gz") implies a gzip file, whereas you are using `BZ2File`, which processes bzip2 (".bz2") files. If you're trying to use a bzip2 decoder to read a gzip file, it certainly won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The extension `.gzip` should have given me a clue.

```
import gzip
import pickle

with gzip.GzipFile('test.gzip', 'rb') as f:
    df = pickle.load(f)
```

All the examples I saw used `bz2` instead of `gzip`.